Model Confidence Set - MCS. How to interpret the output?
I'm computing the MCS (Model Confidence Set) procedure in R for choose the best model based on my data and I would to say how to interpret the output of "MCSProcedure" command.
These are my results but I don't understand what is the means of the columns: "MCS_R", "MCS_M", "v_R" and "v_M".
Can someone help me?
MCS image

Hi Michele Mario Ippolito, welcome to SO. It is important to provide a minimal, reproducible example when asking a question. This link has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks
